# How to show only accounts marked as vendor in a lookup field

Tags: lookup

I'm looking for a way to show all the account that are marked as vendor when the user is clicking on the magnifying glass next to a lookup field on a record. 
I understand that it is not possible due to performance issues of the platform to simply show all accounts that apply that condition, but is it it possible to somehow search for all accounts that the checkbox 'Vendor' is set to true for?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where you want this to happen?
On record creation? or a Custom Visualforce page? or a lightning component?

Comment: On a custom object, in a custom lookup field that look at accounts. I access the record from the custom object tab and click on the magnifying glass next the to field to open the lookup window.

Answer (score 2):

For organizations with lots of records, pre-configuring filters will limit the number of records that your users will have to review and can help them select the correct record.

- To create Lookup Filters, go to Setup…Customize…[Object]…[Field]…Edit…Show Filter Settings.  For custom objects, Setup…Create…[Object]…[Field]…Edit…Show Filter Settings.
- Under the Lookup Filter section, click “Show Filter Settings”, then enter your criteria. Criteria can be configured to filter against specific field values (ex. Active equals “True”) or you can compare different fields against each other. (ex. Contact.Account = Pet.Account)
- I always set my filters to be “Optional”. Setting the Filter Type to “Required” causes the filter criteria to act as a validation rule and if existing records don’t match the criteria of a new filter, users will not be able to save the record. And sometimes, real world situations require users to select a record that don’t match the criteria.
- Provide a Lookup Window Text to explain to your users that the lookup is filtered to show only certain records.
- Now if my users search for a Primary Owner, the results won’t return inactive Contacts or records not associated to the correct household.

  [Lookup Filters Reference 1](https://certifiedondemand.com/salesforce-filtered-relationships/)

  [Lookup Filters Reference 2](http://www.simplysfdc.com/2013/08/salesforce-lookup-filter.html)

  [Lookup Filters Reference 3](http://cloud4good.com/announcements/six-steps-to-improve-user-experience/)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't going to cut it either. This will limit the results shown, but will not enable me to search by checkbox value.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting up 'related look up filter' on this look up field. Apply filter conditions to list only vendor accounts based on the unique identifier.

Comment: This seems to only limit the returned results of the search to records that meets the criteria, it does not show all the records that do, and it does not enable me to search by the field I'm looking for, which is a checkbox field.